# when i add home button code in my Settings Activity the application is closing

Tags: android

this is my MainActivity code for go to Settings Activity

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if (id==R.id.settingsMenuId){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Settings.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

but when i use the home button code in Settings Activity the application is closing
here is my home button code in Settings Activity

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

this is for go back to MainActivity

```
    if (id==android.R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and add the code of your ```navigateUpFromSameTask``` method

Comment: i am new to android, can you please tell me how can i add that method

Comment: Have a look into ```NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);``` and paste the code from within into your post here.

Comment: thanks bro, i got it

Answer (score 0):

When i got you right, just try the **finish()** method:

```
    if (id==android.R.id.home){
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This will close the settings activity and automatically jump into the previous activity